# html div floats and display

Tags: css, html, css-float

i am trying to get "prod_line_fields" and "look_for_fields" on separate lines floating to the left (other html reasons in my page), and then im trying to get "add_field" to be on the same line as the respectful input element. i tried playing with display inline and stuff however i couldn't not figure it out.

CSS

```
#building_infoer_hld{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin:15px 0 0 0;
    width:725px;
}

.add_field{
    width:135px;
    height:24px;
    cursor:pointer;
}


#prod_line_fields{
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
}
.prod_line_inpt{
    width:133px;
    height:22px;
    margin:0 5px 10px 0;
    padding:0 0 0 6px;
    border:#2B4754 1px solid;
}

#look_for_fields{
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
}
.look_for_inpt{
    width:133px;
    height:22px;
    margin:0 5px 10px 0;
    padding:0 0 0 6px;
    border:#2B4754 1px solid;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="building_infoer_hld">
    <div id='title_field'>
        <input class="input_title" name="niche_title" type="text" value="Sample Text" />
    </div>
    <div id='prod_line_fields'>
        <input type="text" class="prod_line_inpt" id="prod_line_0" name="product_line[]" /><div id="add_prod_line" class="add_field"></div>
    </div>
    <div id='look_for_fields'>
        <input type="text" class="look_for_inpt" id="look_for_0" name="look_for[]" /><div id="add_look_for" class="add_field"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/ePZyc/

Comment: sorry for not being clear, im trying to get the following 3 divs on different lines, "title_field", "prod_line_fields", "look_for_fields"
then, for the inputs in them i want the div "add_field" to be on that same line that the input box is on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this styles

```
.add_field{
    width:135px;
    height:24px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}
```

Float added here also add float for these

```
.prod_line_inpt,.look_for_inpt
{ float:left;
}
#look_for_fields{
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
    clear:left;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/tDjzR/6/

Result is here 
http://jsfiddle.net/tDjzR/6/embedded/result/

Comment: worked like a charm thanks! i guess clear is the trick with floating divs, learned a new  rule today

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to make *add_field* as a label you can use this instead

```
<div id="building_infoer_hld">
<div id='title_field'>
    <input class="input_title" name="niche_title" type="text" value="Sample Text" />
</div>
<div id='prod_line_fields'>
    <input type="text" class="prod_line_inpt" id="prod_line_0" name="product_line[]" /><label for="product_line[]">product_line</label>
</div>
<div id='look_for_fields'>
    <input type="text" class="look_for_inpt" id="look_for_0" name="look_for[]" /><label for="product_line[]">look_for</label>
</div>
</div>
```

if you want to stick with your layout, this is my interpretation of the problem:

```
<style type="text/css">
#building_infoer_hld
{
background: #ccc;
}

#prod_line_fields{
margin:10px 0 0 0;
background: blue;
clear: both;
}
#prod_line_fields input, #look_for_fields input{
float:left;
}
#prod_line_fields#add_prod_line{
float: right;
}

.prod_line_inpt,.look_for_inpt{
width:133px;
height:22px;
margin:0 5px 10px 0;
padding:0 0 0 6px;
border:#2B4754 1px solid;
}

#look_for_fields{
margin:10px 0 0 0;
background: yellow;
clear: both;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you can use Sanooj style - the same output with the css that i have provided

Comment: you can color div blocks temporarily to visualize what is going on. :)